# Image maps for Relations

Tags: functions, relations

So I noticed a rather interesting thing about the image function and preimage function. The wikipedia page for Image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)
(notation for image section)

The construction they are describing there can be done for general binary relations $R$, not just for functions. Interesingly the result structures from image and preimage are *still* functions. Using the arrow notation from the article, we then have that:

Given a binary relation $R$ with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. There exist functions:

$R^{\rightarrow}:\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(Y)$

and

$R^{\leftarrow}:\mathcal{P}(Y)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)$

The wikipedia article makes no mention of this, nor is it discussed in their article on binary relations. I'm kinda curious how much is known about this (and it's also worth pointing out that you can iterate this construction and talk about the image map of the image map etc; arrow notation is really useful for this.). I noticed that some of the properties that the image maps have for functions do not hold for general binary relations (e.g. injective function yields injective image map, but that is no longer true for injective binary relations).

Comment: Your question? How much known about this? I am not an expert in this particular topic, but I am sure mathematicians have already considered anything directly related to this. Well, for me it looks, there is nothing particularly interesting about your "recursive" procedure of image of image or preimage of preimage of preimage of ...

Comment: You are asking about a way of viewing the powerset operation $X \mapsto {\cal P}(X)$ as a functor from the category of sets and relations to the category of sets and functions. This kind of thing is well-known and technically useful in universal algebra and other subjects, but doesn't lead to any very deep theory in its own right AFAIK, so I don't know of any references that are likely to be useful to you. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I was kinda suspecting that it was one of those theoretical curiosities that does have much in the way of practical significance. Also seemed too obvious and simple to have been overlooked.